# Alertify.JS and ASP.NET: Call Javascript from Code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, alertify

I have a question.

I am now using the current version of Alertify.js found [here](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/). I wanted to integrate it with my ASP.NET application. When I click the Save button from my Modal Dialog, it proceeds to the code-behind without problems. I've tried "alert("Test");" inside the  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and it does render.

Now when I try to use my custom function located in one of the files I've added, it seems the script does not respond, i.e. Alertify does not show.

Here is the JavaScript code from my custom JS file, my C# Code behind for that Save button, and the ASP.NET Page.

**JS**

```
function callFeedbackMessage(inputType, inputText) {
    var inputFeedback = inputType;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (inputType == 'Error') {
        alertify.error(inputText);
        return false;
    }
    else if (inputType == 'Success') {
        alertify.success(inputText);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alertify.log(inputText, "", 10000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**C# Code Behind of lnkSave_Click**

```
    protected void lnkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Category newCategory = new ProgrammersToolkitLibrary.BOM.Category();
        bool isSuccess = true;

        newCategory.CategoryName = txtCategoryName.Text;
        newCategory.Description = txtDescription.Text;

        isSuccess = CategoryController.CreateNewCategory(newCategory);

        if (isSuccess == true)
        {
            grdCategoriesList.DataBind();
            upCategoriesList.Update();
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "callFeedbackMessage('Success', 'Okay');", true);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

**ASP.NET Page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layout/Layout.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Category_List.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProgrammersToolkit.Views.Maintenance.Categories.Category_List" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div style ="text-align:left;">
        <h3>Article Categories</h3>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddCategoryModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Category</button>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default"><img src="../../../Layout/img/Icon_Excel.gif" /> Export to Excel</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default"><img src="../../../Layout/img/Icon_Excel.gif" /> Import from Excel</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default">Search</asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReset" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default">Reset</asp:LinkButton>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-lg-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCategoriesList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdCategoriesList" runat="server" CssClass = "table table-hover table-responsive" Width="100%" 
                    DataSourceID="odsCategoriesList" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="NotSet" BorderWidth="0px"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="<< First" LastPageText="Last >>" NextPageText="Next >"
                                        Position="Bottom" PreviousPageText="< Previous" />

                    <Columns>                 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="input-group-addon" ItemStyle-CssClass="input-group-addon">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectItem" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Category Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategoryName" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkCategoryName_Command" 
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' CommandName='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' 
                                    Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </Columns> 

                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </asp:GridView>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
    
      </div>
  
      <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCategoriesList" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" TypeName="ProgrammersToolkitLibrary.Controller.CategoryController" 
          SelectMethod="GetListOfCategories" SelectCountMethod="GetListOfCategoriesCount"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="AddCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Category</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style = "width: 30%;"><label for="txtCategoryName">Category Name:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style = "width:30%; vertical-align:text-top;"><label for="txtDescription">Description:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="lnkSave_Click" ClientIDMode="Static">Save</asp:LinkButton>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Thank you.

Ju-chan

Comment: Is the `e` in `e.preventDefault()` defined?

Comment: Not really. I saw it in alertify samples, so I think it is needed. I tried removing it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to me that the JS code is causing the problem (since a simple call to alert works). Maybe the console log will provide some clue. You can access it by pressing Ctrl+J in Chrome and FireFox, or F12 in IE.

Comment: My ASP.NET Link button causes postback, which makes my whole page refresh. How could I prevent the button to postback.

Comment: I think the JS code is the problem.